# Can limit IE(Firefox) to open only website in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I have an app that runs in Windows startup.

This app allows the user to run a special app and doesn't allow him to open the start menu.

Can I limit IE to open only website with c#?

Comment: please explain "open only website" - do you mean lock it down so that it can only access one domain?

Comment: Access one page of special website, foe example mysite.com/data.php

Comment: Awesomium is the perfect fit, you can build your own UI and no need for an Address bar.

Comment: Restricting to only one web site is the least of your worries. The user can go to File.Open and start launching arbitrary programs!

Comment: @RaymondChen : I close start menu, and the users don't have access to any programes.

Comment: They can still run programs from File.Open. The way to solve this is to configure the network to allow access only to the domains you want. A custom proxy or proxy script would probably do nicely. But you still have to fix the "user can use File.Open to run any program" problem.

Comment: @RaymondChen : thanks a lot,how to use proxy script?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set `Global Windows Proxy`

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll")]
public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);
public const int INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39;
public const int INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37;
static bool settingsReturn, refreshReturn;
```

And imply the code:

```
RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
registry.SetValue("ProxyServer", YOURPROXY);

// These lines implement the Interface in the beginning of program 
// They cause the OS to refresh the settings, causing IP to realy update
settingsReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
refreshReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```